# How to change color of hyperlink to an external URL?

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing

I have written the following command to create a link with black or green color :

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[margin=1.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
colorlinks=true,
linktoc=all,
linkcolor=black,
}
\begin{document}
For online \LaTeX ~solution click on the  link :
\href{http://stackexchange.com/}{http://stackexchange.com/}
\end{document}
```

Produces :

[image]

I want to change the link color as my choice ? How can I do that ?

Comment: `\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,linkcolor=,urlcolor=black}`

Comment: Much better and much more simple is the option `hidelinks`!

Comment: @Speravir The OP might have chosen "black" as (bad) example of a desired colour.

Comment: @Jubobs Yes, you maybe right!